# What's the best strategy for dumping very large python dictionaries to a database?

Tags: python, database

I'm writing something that essentially refines and reports various strings out of an enormous python dictionary (the source file for the dictionary is XML over a million lines long).

I found mongodb yesterday and was delighted to see that it accepts python dictionaries easy as you please... until it refused mine because the dict object is larger than the BSON size limit of 16MB.

I looked at GridFS for a sec, but that won't accept any python object that doesn't have a .read attribute.

Over time, this program will acquire many of these mega dictionaries; I'd like to dump each into a database so that at some point I can compare values between them.

What's the best way to handle this?  I'm awfully new to all of this but that's fine with me :) It seems that a NoSQL approach is best; the structure of these is generally known but can change without notice. Schemas would be nightmarish here.

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Is there no way to transform the dictionaries into some intermediate format?

Comment: The trouble with this dictionary situation is that the XML it's generated from is malformed; all leaf elements are named <value> instead of a properly unique element tag.  There's a name= attribute that I use to give the elements a unique name.  

But the parent/container elements _are_ uniquely tagged, so there's some weird blending of this + that to make it work.

Comment: The format isn’t changed/fixed when it’s parsed and transformed into a dictionary? Could you share an example of the XML?

Comment: Oh it's certainly transformed!  If it weren't, the leaf-elements all named <value> would be a pile of text in a list.  I'll stub up an example; the original data is full of PII so I'll need to muddy the water a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Have your considered using Pandas? Yes Pandas does not natively accept xmls but if you use ElementTree from xml (standard library) you should be able to read it into a Pandas data frame and do what you need with it including refining strings and adding more data to the data frame as you get it.

Comment: How is Panda a database?

Comment: @LongNguyen I think they meant that OP could use a DataFrame as a sort of intermediate step, which would then make importing the data to the DB simpler.

Comment: Wouldn't this ultimately still leave the size of the dataset-to-be-stuffed-into-mongo < 16MB? Even after its experience in Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

So I've decided that this problem is more of a data design problem than a python situation.  I'm trying to load a lot of unstructured data into a database when I probably only need 10% of it.  I've decided to save the refined xml dictionary as a pickle on a shared filesystem for cool storage and use mongo to store the refined queries I want from the dictionary.

That'll reduce their size from 22MB to 100K.

Thanks for chatting with me about this :)